# Google API responds with 403 forbidden with no reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to use the Google youtube analytics API but my requests are receiving this response:

```
{ code: 403,
  message: 'Forbidden',
  errors: [ { message: 'Forbidden', domain: 'global', reason: 'forbidden' } ]
}
```

Before this, I was getting a response that said I needed to enable the youtube analytics service for my service account (which I did).

What is causing this? How am I supposed to debug this when the reason is just "forbidden"?

Here is the code creating the request:

```
const result = await youtubeAnalytics.reports.query({
  "ids": "channel==MINE",
  "startDate": "2017-01-01",
  "endDate": "2017-12-31",
  "metrics": "views,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,averageViewPercentage,subscribersGained",
  "dimensions": "day",
  "sort": "day"
})
```

And here is the code creating the `youtubeAnalytics` instance:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const googleServiceAccount = require('../google-service-account.dev');
const scopes = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
];

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  googleServiceAccount.client_email,
  null,
  googleServiceAccount.private_key,
  scopes,
  null
);

const youtubeAnalytics = google.youtubeAnalytics({
  version: 'v2',
  auth: jwtClient,
});
```

The service account was created through my google dev console and has the role "project > viewer".

**Edit:** Tried switching `scope` to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly` since I'm trying to access youtube analytics (same result).

**Edit 2:** Also tried using the youtube data API just to see if it would work and it does. I'm able to send search requests to the data API, but I can't seem to send query requests to the analytics API (this is with both scopes).

**Edit 3:** I had things working briefly when I added the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly` scope but now I'm back to getting the same useless 403 'forbidden' responses.

Comment: In light of recent censorship issues, (Info Wars) is there any chance that the channel is a target?  I would look to technical reasons first, but the thought crossed my mind.

Comment: @jeffld Nah. I'm testing using my own personal channel which has no content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant access to the google acc you are using in https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/

[image]

Use the button **'Grant Access'** and add google acc that you are using